# For $x>0$ let $f(x)=x^{2/3}(6-x)^{1/3}$, then find the number of solutions of $f(x)=f^{-1}(x); x\in (0,4)$

Tags: functions, inverse-function

> For $x>0$ let $f(x)=x^{2/3}(6-x)^{1/3}$, then find the number of solutions of $f(x)=f^{-1}(x); x\in (0,4)$

$\displaystyle f'(x)=\frac{2(6-x)^{1/3}}{3x^{1/3}}+\frac{x^{2/3}}{3(6-x)^{1/3}}$, since $f'(x)$ is always positive this means that $f(x)$ is an increasing function.

Let $f(x)=y$, then $y^3=x^2(6-x)=6x^2-x^3$, is there any way to express $x$ in terms of $y$? How can we proceed after this?

Comment: The equation $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ is equivalent to this equation $f(f(x))=x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us show first that for a strictly increasing function $f$

- (A) $x$ is a solution for the equation $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$

if and only if

- (B) $x$ is a solution for the equation $x=f(x)$.

One direction is clear. The other one. So let us start with (A) and show (B). First, $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ is equivalent with $f(f(x))=x$. (We apply $f$, which is injective.)

Assume (B) is false. (We get soon a contradiction.) Then we have either $x<f(x)$ or $f(x)<x$.

- The first case, $x<f(x)$. Then applying $f$ we get $f(x)<f(f(x))$. Put together, $x<f(x)<f(f(x))$, a contradiction.
- The second case, $f(x)<x$. Then applying $f$ we get $f(f(x))<f(x)$. Put together, $f(f(x))<f(x)<x$, a contradiction.

---

It remains now to solve $y^3=x^2(6-x)$ on $(0,4)$, knowing $y=x$, this leads to $x=6-x$, so $x=3$.

---

The above solution solves the problem without addressing the intermediate question: "*... is there any way to express $x$ in terms of $y$?*" - well, i will try to say some words on this, although it may seem completely useless. The following "explains" somehow the relation between $x$ and $y$ by giving a *parametrization* of the curve $y=f(x)$.

---

Observe first that for $x>0$ the corresponding value of $y:=f(x)$ is also $>0$. So we may, and do build the fraction $t=y/x$. So $y=tx$.

(This is the usual trick in algebraic geometry, to try to parametrize a curve, here the algebraic curve with (singular) equation $y^3=x^2(6-x)$, by the slope passing through the (singular) point $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$. This may make some sense for some readers, please ignore if this makes no sense. But this allows me to refer to [Maria Agnesi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_Gaetana_Agnesi), she used and popularized this "trick" in some special examples, she is maybe not the first one, but she is the one i know.)

Then we get successively for $x\in(0,4)$, $y=f(x)>0$, first written down in a *formal* computation, the result of the computation will be used only:
$$
\begin{aligned}
y^3 &= x^2(6-x)\ ,\\
t^3x^3 &= x^2(6-x)\ ,\\
t^3x &= 6-x\ ,\\
(t^3+1)x &= 6\ ,\\
x &=\frac 6{t^3+1}\ , \qquad\text{ so}\\
y &= tx= \frac {6t}{t^3+1}\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and in this way we get a ((bi)rational) parametrization of the curve.

---

In other words, the graph $y=f(x)$ is parametrized (on the interval $x\in(0,4)$) by the points of the shape
$$
P(t) := \left(\ \frac 6{t^3+1}\ ,\ \frac {6t}{t^3+1}\ \right)\ .
$$
(The parameter $t$ lives in the corresponding interval $(0,2^{-1/3})$ i think...)

A point on the graph of the inverse function, drawn by reflection in the first quadrant bisector, has "switched" coordinates, so it is a point of the shape
$$
Q(u) := \left(\ \frac {6u}{u^3+1}\ ,\ \frac {6}{u^3+1}\ \right)\ .
$$
Let us now intersect the two graphs. This means, we are searching for suitable parameters $t,u$ (in the appropriate range), so that $P(t)=Q(u)$.

Assume such a condition is satisfied. Then we build the quotient $y/x$, getting, after denominator simplifications
$$ \frac {6t}6=\frac6{6u}\ ,$$
so $u=1/t$. Let us plug this relation in $P(t)=Q(u)$, we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(\ \frac 6{t^3+1}\ ,\ \frac {6t}{t^3+1}\ \right)
&=P(t)\\
&=Q(1/t)\\
&=
\left(\ \frac {6/t}{1/t^3+1}\ ,\ \frac {6}{1/t^3+1}\ \right)
\\
&=
\left(\ \frac {6t^2}{1+t^3}\ ,\ \frac {6t^3}{1+t^3}\ \right)
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This implies $t=1$. So $x=y=6/2=3$. So getting the point(s) of intersection of the two graphs, means getting the point(s) of intersection with $y=x$, i.e. the fixed points... And there is only one fixed point, $3$,
well, we have to check this. (Since all the implications above go in one direction, finally the point $(3,3)$ is the only possible intersection of the graphs, but this has to be checked.) Indeed: $f(3) = 3^{2/3}(6-3)^{1/3}
=3^{2/3\ +\ 1/3}=3^1=3$.

(In this case, we intersect two "very particular", indeed reflected curves, so solving algebraically does not make too much sense. But in general...)

Answer (score 1):

As you checked, for $x \in (0,4)$, $f(x)$ is injective. Thus $f^{-1}(x)$ can be defined.
Now note that, $f^{-1}(x)$ is merely a reflection of $f(x)$ about the line $y=x$. Hence, if $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$, then this means that both curves meet, which can only happen on the line $y=x$.

Thus, we can simply look for solutions of $f(x)=x$ in the given interval. Clearly, $x=3$ is the only possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is just as well to work with $g(x)=f(6x)/6$  over $(0,2/3)$. So let

$$p(x,y) = y^3 - y^2 + x^3$$
and
$$q(x,y) = y^3 + x^3 - x^2$$
so that $y=g(x)$ implies $q(x,y)=0$ and $y=g^{-1}(x)$ implies $p(x,y)=0$. Using generalized Euclidean division to eliminate $y$ gives

$$(y^2-(x-1)y+x^2)p(x,y) - (y^2-xy+x^2+x-1)q(x,y) = r(x)$$
where
$$r(x) = x^2(2x-1)$$
so that $g(x)=g^{-1}(x)$ implies $r(x)=0$. Of the roots of $r$, only $x=\tfrac{1}{2}$ is admissible, corresponding to $x=3$ for the unscaled function.